# Definition of variables in propositional calculus

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Let $\tilde P$ be a first order algebra, and consider the definitions below:

[image]

I'm confused about the very last thing: what $y\not\in V(c)$ means. $c$ has a free variable, so what does it mean to say $V(c)$?

(This is from [an algebraic introduction to mathematical logic](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781475744910)).

Comment: I think that you have to improve the title: the Defs are in **Ch.IV Predicate Calculus** and the definitions are relative to *individual* variables, and not to propositional ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that :

> $w_1=(\forall x)c(x)$

and

> $w_2=(\forall y)c(y)$

and : $x \ne y$ and $y$ is not *free* in $c=c(x)$.

If not, the free occurrence of $y$ in the sub-formula $c(x)$ will be free in $w_1$ while it will be "captured" by the quantifier $(\forall y)$ in $w_2$.